# bootstrap-table JS extension functionality for ReactJS components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have downloaded through NPM (npmjs.com) the bootstrap-table package. This offers some fantastic functionality to set up tables or datagrids in my ReactJS application. However there are several addon js files and css files that are required for extra "bit" of functionality. For example Sticky Column headers that move when you scroll left, or fixed first column for scrolling left or right. The examples on the developers website all refer to local script inclusions :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="extensions/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.css">
<script src="extensions/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js"></script>
```

and not necessarily to NPM installations.

The question I have is do I need to try and hunt down the packages on NPM or can I download the usual js and css extension files from github, place them into assets/js or assets/css folders and then import them into my index.js and index.hml files? (Which is the professional stance to follow)?

Apologies but am new to ReactJS (have done several courses online) and trying to execute my application as a learning project.

Answer (score 0):

I might have answered my own question in the form of:

[4 Ways to Add External JavaScript Files in React](https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668)